# request.get vs CURL in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request

I have an URL mapped as

`router.route('/user').get(policies.isAuthenticated, policies.isCurrentUser, userController.get);`

When I access the URL with CURL or from the browser it runs through all of the chained methods. But when I access it from NodeJS it only runs the last method, userController.get. I'm using the following request method.

```
request.get({
  url: testURL,
  body: user.id,
  json: true
}, function(err, res: express.Request) { ... });
```

Do I need to include some options in request.get so that it acts like a 'proper' request?

Comment: A client cannot manipulate which middleware will or won't get called, so there's something else going on. Running your app while setting `DEBUG=*` (env var) should show you which middleware gets called during a request.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The body param isn't valid JSON. Also thanks for letting me know about the DEBUG=* flag!